# Evaluating functions from parent function in child function

Tags: r, eval, parent-child

Say I have a function:

```
MyFunction=function(x,y,z,thelist){            
   a = x+3    
   b = y+4
   c = z+2

   mylist=thelist   
   myfunc1=function(form=a) a+2         
   myfunc2=function(form=b) b+2         
   myfunc3=function(form=c) c+2         

   function(...){         
      .x = as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]         
      CombinedList = lapply(seq_along(mylist), function (y,.x) {            
         numbercols = length(eval(.x[[1]])(form=eval(formals(eval(.x[[1]]))$form))[[1]])                
         numbercolsplusone = numbercols+1            
         elementz = matrix(NA,nrow=length(.x),ncol=numbercolsplusone)

         for (i in seq_along(.x)) {                        
           elementz[i,1:numbercols] = eval(.x[[i]])(form=eval(formals(eval(.x[[i]]))$form))[[y]] 

           elementz[i,numbercolsplusone] = substr(as.character(.x[[i]]),1,nchar(as.character(.x[[i]]))-4)                
         }   
         ....
         Some more calculations....
         ....

      },.x)

      return(CombinedList)  
   }
}
```

I then choose, say `myfunc1` and `myfunc2` from the `parent function`, and call my toyfunction:

```
try = Myfunction(x,y,z,thelist)(myfunc1,myfunc2)
```

This is a toyfunction, and my real function is much longer and takes a lot of time to calculate. I guess the problem lies in the for-loop inside the child function - probably my use of `eval`.

This function takes longer time to calculate then the the other similar function which only differs in that I call all the functions in my parent function before proceeding to the child function, `function(...){`. And not choose functions like in this toy-example.

Is there some other, quicker way?

Comment: @joran Thanks! Any suggestions?

Comment: I was editing just to make it readable. I can't understand anything about what you're asking at all.

Comment: I have to agree. It seems a lot of this code is superfluous, and without a use case , it's unclear what the goal is. On R-help Jim Holtman's tag line is something along the lines of "don't tell me how you failed to do it; tell what should be done."

Comment: @DWin Thanks for your comments! I am writing a function to analyze time series data. The code above aims to pick some specific functions from the parent function into the child function `function(...){}`. Those specific functions take different formal default arguments. So the `eval` in the child function evaluates those default arguments. It works, but is very slow. So, I thought I could ask the R wizards here:)